# Building MongoDB queries in Java

Tags: java, mongodb

This is the query that works in the mongo shell, which I am trying to recreate dynamically in Java:

```
db.contacts.find(
    {
        $and: [
            {"site" : { $in : ["FR", "NL"] }}, 
            {"country" : {$in : ["Belgium"]}}
        ]
    }
);
```

I have my values of site and country stored in `String[]` like so:

```
String[] sites = {"NL", "FR"};
String[] countries = {"Belgium"};
```

And my query builder looks like so:

```
    Document query = new Document();
    Document st = new Document();
    Document ct = new Document();
    List<Document> lst = new ArrayList<>();

    if(sites != null){
        st.put("site", new Document("$in", Arrays.asList(sites)));
        lst.add(st);
    }

    if(countries != null){
        ct.put("country", new Document("$in", Arrays.asList(countries)));
        lst.add(ct);
    }

    query.put("$and", lst);
```

When I print query this is what I get:

```
Document{{$and=[
Document{{site=Document{{$in=[NL,  FR]}}}}, 
Document{{country=Document{{$in=[Belgium]}}}}
]}}
```

But this query returns no results, while the one I pasted on the top works fine.

If I run query like so:

```
Document{{$and=[Document{{site=Document{{$in=[NL,  FR]}}}}]}}
```

it returns only documents with NL marked as site, but not FR and vice versa is FR is before NL in the array, it would return only FR and not NL documents.

EDIT: I figured it out! Basically it didn't like converting `Arrays.asList(sites)`, I had to initialize new List like so: `List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(sites));` and it worked as expected.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. I tested your query in Java and it works as expected - returns both NL and FR. What version of mongo driver are you using and what is your mongoDB version?

Comment: Driver is 3.2.2 and MongoDB is 3.2.3

Answer (score 0):

Can you try re-using the same object for both the filters? Below is an example:

```
BasicDBObject whereCondition = new BasicDBObject();

whereCondition.put("site", new BasicDBObject("$in", Arrays.asList(sites)));
whereCondition.put("country", new BasicDBObject("$in", Arrays.asList(countries)));
//execute the query
```

Comment: Need a valid $and statement, it takes an array [].

Comment: Can you please post the complete code of method that is querying mongo?

Comment: That is it, all I do after my query is built is: `contacts.find(query);`

Comment: Hmm.. Can you please check whether your application is connected to same mongo database as the one you queried?

Comment: Yeah, it was connected, apparently instead of using Arrays.asList I had to initialize List and use that. Solved it. Thanks.